# Password Encoding - BCrypt - Not Authorising Hashed Passwords, authorising on plain text only

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I got a pet project i have been slowly chipping at and recently i decided to incorporate BCrypt password encoding for users.

Problem i am encountering is that it is never authorising any users now that I have it on, and i cannot figure out why.

Hope you guys can help.

Below is the configuration within my SecurityConfig.java file

```
@Autowired
private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

@Override
protected void registerAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
}


@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

My controller that registers new users and logs them in:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user_create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String createUser(@ModelAttribute User user) {
    user.setPlain(user.getPassword());
    user.setPassword(BCrypt.hashpw(user.getPassword(),BCrypt.gensalt()));
    userInterface.saveUser(user);
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

Creation of new users works perfectly (loads it into DB) and result looks like this:

```
ID | USERNAME | PLAIN_PASSWORD | HASHED_PASSWORD
1  | hash     | hash           | $2a$10$BYpLI.Dd06HS1myhxxeyb.lZ/74lfYVXSk9Tuy.iYTzy4t2Yx5FtW
```

What is the reason i cannot authorise users?

**UPDATE 1**

I have also got another user added (through backend) so i have 2 users looking like this

```
ID | USERNAME | PLAIN_PASSWORD | HASHED_PASSWORD
1  | hash     | hash           | $2a$10$BYpLI.Dd06HS1myhxxeyb.lZ/74lfYVXSk9Tuy.iYTzy4t2Yx5FtW
2  | admin    | admin          | admin
```

With the setup above i can login using "admin" and "admin" even tho its not hashed and even tho i have the password encoder on.

**UPDATE 2**

Database is managed by Hibernate and the setup is as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "username")
private String login;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "hashed_password")
private String password;

@Column(name = "plain_password")
private String plain;

// GETTERS AND SETTERS //
}
```

Comment: Do you actually have 'plain_password' and 'hashed_password' fields in the database? If so, how are you configuring the authentication schema?

Comment: Entity that retrieves the user details references hashed_password as password field. I use hibernate for my database management.

Comment: Why aren't you using `BCryptPasswordEncoder` to encode the password as well?

Comment: As an extra i have also tried with BCrpyPasswordEncoder.encode(password). Works great and i end up with the above results. But the passwordEncoder in security config doesn't work. It literally does 0 encoding and that was proven by being able to login with plaintext passwords.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've identified the problem....and it was really simple.

changed the following:

```
@Override
protected void registerAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
}
```

to the below

```
@Override
protected void registerAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(customUserService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder).and
jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource);
}
```

moved it from HttpSecurity configuration.