# Spring security encoded password does not look like BCrypt while values are equals

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm using spring security with BCrypt and I have some trouble to resolve the problem.

So my snippet where I'm setting the `passwordEncoder`

```
    @Autowired
    public void configureAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder
                .userDetailsService(this.userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
```

In the DB password is correctly saved as BCrypt, but when I'm trying to authenticate I'm receiving an error

```
Encoded password does not look like BCrypt

    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "exception": "org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException",
```

Comment: This answer should work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23456383/password-encoding-bcrypt-not-authorising-hashed-passwords-authorising-on-pl.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same exception. In my case, I had manually added passwords into the database, and the problem occurred because I had generated them with an online BCrypt generator which used `$2y$` prefix in hashes — and Java `BCryptPasswordEncoder` uses `$2a$` one. So, I just used another generator.

Comment: [This calculator](https://www.dailycred.com/article/bcrypt-calculator) generates according to Spring Security $2a$ prefix. While [this](https://bcrypt-generator.com/) generates with $2y$.

Answer (score 0):

In bcrypt hashing algorithm, each time, a different hash value of length 60 is generated, for example

$2a$10$LOqePml/koRGsk2YAIOFI.1YNKZg7EsQ5BAIuYP1nWOyYRl21dlne

A common mistake, the length of the “password” column (users table) is less than 60, for example, password VARCHAR(45), and some databases will truncate the data automatically. So, you always get the warning “Encoded password does not look like BCrypt”.

To solve it, make sure the length of “password” column is at least 60.

Ref: https://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-encoded-password-does-not-look-like-bcrypt/

Comment: Column has a length of VARCHAR(255)

Comment: In my case, I am using postgresql, and my password column was char(128). If the password column is char(128) and length of password is 64, 64 spaces are added. That is why authentication always failed. I changed it to varchar(128) and the authentication is working now.